# what can you do to debug linear optimisation when using R lp

Tags: r, debugging, optimization

High level question is in the subject title: what can you do to debug linear optimisation when using R lp.

The detailed issue is that I have a working program adapted from: [http://pena.lt/y/2014/07/24/mathematically-optimising-fantasy-football-teams/][1]

Based on player data it chooses an optimal 15 man squad - handy for start of year or when you can change all players

I have changed it to:
1) Read player data from an Excel file (which I can supply - just tell me how)
2) Add 2 constraints to show players I definitely want to include in team and those I definitely don't.

Player data has the following columns:

web_name
team_name
type_name
now_cost
total_points
InTeam
In
Out

Good start, so I go about modelling the normal weeks when you can only transfer 1 player. I think I have the right constraint but now lp chooses about 200 players for me - not 15. Something very wrong - but I can't see it how it gets there.

I have tried going back from my new code to strip out the new feature and it still works.
I have tried removing the In/Out constraints and keeping the new "1 change" constraint. Same result.

Have upgraded packages and to latest R

Any pointers?

Code is

```
#Straight lift from Web - http://pena.lt/y/2014/07/24/mathematically-optimising-fantasy-football-teams/

# plus extra constraints to exclude and include specific players via Excel In/Out columns
# This variant looks to limit changes (typically 1 or 2) for a normal week

library(gdata)  
library(lpSolve)
library(stringr)
library(RCurl)
library(jsonlite)
library(plyr)
excelfile<-"C:/Users/mike/Documents/FF/Start2015R.xlsx"
df=read.xls(excelfile)
# Constants
num_teams = 20
num_constraints = 8
# InTeam,In,Out,Cost + 4 positions
#Create the constraints
num_gk = 2
num_def = 5
num_mid = 5
num_fwd = 3
team_size = num_gk + num_def + num_mid + num_fwd
#max_cost = 1000
max_cost = 998
#max_cost = 2000
max_changes = 2
min_same = team_size - max_changes
# Create vectors to constrain by position
df$Goalkeeper = ifelse(df$type_name == "Goalkeeper", 1, 0)
df$Defender = ifelse(df$type_name == "Defender", 1, 0)
df$Midfielder = ifelse(df$type_name == "Midfielder", 1, 0)
df$Forward = ifelse(df$type_name == "Forward", 1, 0)
# Create vector to constrain by max number of players allowed per team
team_constraint = unlist(lapply(unique(df$team_name), function(x, df){
ifelse(df$team_name==x, 1, 0)
}, df=df))
# next we need the constraint directions. First is for MinSame
const_dir <- c(">=","=","=","=", "=", "=", "=", rep("<=", 21))
# The vector to optimize against
objective = df$total_points
# Put the complete matrix together
# nrow is number of constraints
const_mat = matrix(c(df$Inteam,df$In,df$Out,df$Goalkeeper, df$Defender, df$Midfielder, df$Forward,
df$now_cost, team_constraint),
nrow=( num_constraints + length(unique(df$team_name))),
byrow=TRUE)
const_rhs = c(min_same ,sum(df$In),0,num_gk, num_def, num_mid, num_fwd, max_cost, rep(3, num_teams))
# And solve the linear system
x = lp ("max", objective, const_mat, const_dir, const_rhs, all.bin=TRUE, all.int=TRUE)
print(arrange(df[which(x$solution==1),], desc(Goalkeeper), desc(Defender), desc(Midfielder), desc(Forward), desc(total_points)))
print (df[which(x$solution==1),"web_name",drop=FALSE], row.names = FALSE)
# what changed
df[which(x$solution != df$InTeam),"web_name",drop=FALSE]
```

Comment: You can provide the input by posting the output of this R command: `dput(df)`.  Please reduce your code and data to the minimum required to illustrate the problem.  That includes cutting down the code so that it does not use a long list of package dependencies and cutting down the code size.  It's also not clear what the problem is.  The subject as stated is too broad.

Comment: Sorry G. Grothendieck - I guess there were 2 questions:
1. In general how do you debug the use of a big function like lp? How can you look at how it got to its answers
2. Please help with a specific problem
I have now fixed the specific problem. 
Too embarrassed by the mistake to own up to it – so happy to leave there.
I have learnt on point 1:
• Try to remove constraints until you get to a “legal” solution (possible but not subject to all final constraints). Then build back up again.
• Print each of the parameters fed into lp to make sure they look like you thought they would